# If independent on the $\pi$ system, then independent on the $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\pi_1, ...,\pi_n$ be collections of measurable sets on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, each closed under intersection. Suppose
\begin{align*}
P(A_1\cap...\cap\ A_n)=P(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot P(A_n),
\end{align*}
for all $A_i \in \pi_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Now I want to show that the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\pi_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are independent, using an application of the $\pi$-$\lambda$-theorem.

I have already proven the proposition when $n=2$, now I am confused how can I use induction to continue my proof.

Here is a sketch of my proof for $n=2$.

$\forall U \in \sigma(\pi_1)$, define $G_U= \{ V\ \in \sigma(\pi_2) ; P(V \cap U)=P(U)P(V)\}$, then I show it $G_U$ is a dynkin system.

Obviously, if $U \in \pi_1$, then $G_U= \sigma (\pi_2)$, I hope it also holds for $U \in \sigma(\pi_1)$, which is equivalent to show $\pi_2 \subset G_U$.

> The trick is $\forall A \in \pi_2$, $G_A = \{ B\ \in \sigma(\pi_1) ; P(B \cap A)=P(A)P(B)\}=\sigma(\pi_1)$. Ends the proof.

I tried for $n=3$, but stuck.

$\forall U \in \sigma(\pi_1), \forall V \in \sigma(\pi_2)$, similarly define $G_{U,V}=\{ C\ \in \sigma(\pi_3) ; P(C \cap U \cap V)=P(C)P(U)P(V)\}$, then I can show $G_{U,V}$ is a dynkin system **but can not show $\pi_3 \subset G_{U,V}$.** The trick I used before can not be used here.

$\forall A \in \pi_3$, If I define $G_A=\{ B\ \in \sigma(\pi_1) ; P(B \cap A)=P(A)P(B)\}$, then $G_A =\sigma(\pi_1)$, If I define $G_A=\{ B\ \in \sigma(\pi_2) ; P(B \cap A)=P(A)P(B)\}$, then $G_A =\sigma(\pi_2)$. Both not enough show the results.

Good answer :
@MISC {1665571,
TITLE = {Independent $\sigma$-algebras using $\pi$-$\lambda$-theorem},
AUTHOR = {John (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/105625/john)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665571 (version: 2016-02-21)},
EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665571},
URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665571}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$C = \{ A_{j} \dots\cap A_{k} : A_{i}\in \pi_{i}, 1\leq j\leq k\leq n-1\}$$ $C$ is closed under intersections and is independent from $\pi_{n}$. It follows from the case $n=2$ you have proven that $\sigma(C)$ and $\sigma(\pi_{n})$ are independent. Now $\pi_{i} \subseteq C$ for $i\leq n-1$ so $ \sigma(\bigcup\limits_{i\leq n-1}\sigma(\pi_{i}))$ and $\sigma(\pi_{n})$ are independent. So
$$P(B_{1}\cap\dots \cap B_{n})=P(B_{1}\cap \dots B_{n-1})P(B_{n})$$
For $B_{i} \in \sigma(\pi_{i})$. The result follows from a simple induction argument on $n$.